# How to determine if assembly has been ngen'd?

Tags: .net, ngen

How can you determine whether a particular .Net assembly has already been ngen'd or not? I need to check from code. Even invoking the command-line would be fine. At the moment I can't see any way of determining this.

Comment: In code? From the command line? Interactively? What? It has to be in the file properties somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to find your assembly in "ngen cache" (C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2XXXXXXX).

Сached assemblies will have the following format name: 
  *[basename].**ni**.[baseextension]*.

Comment: Windows 7 seems to store them is a slightly different location, and with no '.ni.' in the name: C:\Windows\assembly

Comment: Very strange. I have Windows 7 installed, and "ngen cash" path is "C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\".

Comment: I have Win7 and you cannot navigate to those folders using the Windows Explorer. You should use `cmd` and `dir` inside the `assembly` folder.

Answer (score 7):

**Check From Code**

Check if we are loading an native image for the executing assembly. I am looking for the pattern "\assemblyname.ni" in loaded module filename property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyTestsApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool Main(string[] args)
        {

            Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            ProcessModule[] modules = new ProcessModule[process.Modules.Count]; 
            process.Modules.CopyTo(modules,0);

            var niQuery = from m in modules where m.FileName.Contains("\\"+process.ProcessName+".ni") select m.FileName;
            bool ni = niQuery.Count()>0 ?true:false;

            if (ni)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Native Image: "+niQuery.ElementAt(0));
            }
            else
           {
                Console.WriteLine("IL Image: " + process.MainModule.FileName);
           }

            return ni;
        }
    }
}
```

**Command Line Solution:**

Run "ngen display " on command prompt.

Example:

ngen display MyTestsApp.exe

If installed, it prints out something like
*Native Images:
MyTestsApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null*

and returns 0 (%errorlevel%)

Otherwise, it prints out:

*Error: The specified assembly is not installed.*

and returns -1

Comment: This is a good way of going about it, thanks for laying it out. The ngen documentation is missing a lot of the error codes that you should be expecting.