# Autorun Ngen.exe on First Run

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, build, ngen

My app doesn't have an installer. It is portable but I need to run `ngen.exe` on it because it runs on startup.

Is it recommended to autorun `ngen.exe` on the first run of the app? Will it cause any problems later? Is there a built in way to do it?

Comment: Running ngen requires administrator privileges, I wouldn't recommend that. Are you using .NET 4.5? If yes you could use the [ProfileOptimization Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.profileoptimization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why do you need to ngen it? Is it really slow on first run? Does first run really matter? I mean if user has to wait 2 seconds once in their lifetime, it does not sound like a big deal, does it? Please describe the need in more detail.

Comment: I mean on first run it should automatically ngen so that on subsequent runs the app runs faster.

Comment: ngen is a developer tool it is supposed to be run before distribution of the app. Unless VS is installed on the client computer they won't have the ability to run ngen.

Comment: @Bender, i think you could make this in an answer? It says it all.

Comment: @Bender Can't we package ngen with the app itself? Installers of other apps come with ngen.

Comment: Why do you think you need to package ngen for the user? If you as the developer run ngen before distributing the app the work has already been done.  It's a bit like you asking 'I want to distribute my source code and the VS complier, so that the user can compile my app when he wants to run it.' My answer would be compile the app and distribute the exe

Comment: @Bender Can you explain further? How many native images will I have to compile on different platforms? Paint.NET installer runs ngen after installation.

Comment: Why not just use a free installer like InnoSetup? Then you can bundle and script whatever you like.

Comment: @steve The app has to be portable, shouldn't require installation.

Comment: @Bender: While they clearly resonate with others, your comments that "ngen is a developer tool it is supposed to be run before distribution of the app" and "[i]f you as the developer run ngen before distributing the app the work has already been done" are incorrect.  See [a related discussion on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fedf158d-b4c7-4338-ae23-6fab78f963af/1-is-ngen-run-by-the-developer-before-distributing-the-app-2-is-the-msil-code-also-included-in?forum=clr) about this misconception.

Comment: There cannot be 1+1=2 answer here. More information is required.
 1. Is you application big? What is size of your application?
 2. What is .NET Framework you are using?
 3. Does you application run in full trust?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *Is it recommended to autorun ngen.exe on the first run of the app?*

I have never read or heard any such recommendation, but it is an interesting idea.

I say go for it and test whether it works for your situation (which is interesting insofar as your "portable"/"no-installer" requirement).

## *Is there a built in way to do it?*

There is not a built-in way to run NGen on the first run of an app; but it can be done as the PoC below demonstrates.

### PoC code

The following PoC code incorporates [code from a related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593260/1810429).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace SelfNgenPoC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
             * Check whether the app has been NGen'd with code adapted from
             * https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593260/1810429, which also outlines
             * an alternative approach - by running...
             *     ngen.exe display <assemblyPath>
             * ...and checking the result - 0 if the app is already NGen'd and
             * -1 if it is not.
             */

            Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            ProcessModule[] modules = new ProcessModule[process.Modules.Count];
            process.Modules.CopyTo(modules, 0);

            var niQuery =
                from m in modules
                where m.FileName.Contains(@"\" + process.ProcessName + ".ni")
                select m.FileName;
            bool ni = niQuery.Count() > 0 ? true : false;

            // FORNOW: for PoC debugging and sanity checking
            if (ni)
                Console.WriteLine("Native Image: " + niQuery.ElementAt(0));
            else
                Console.WriteLine("IL Image: " + process.MainModule.FileName);

            /*
             * NGen the app if not.
             */

            if (!ni)
            {
                // FORNOW: for PoC debugging and sanity checking
                Console.WriteLine("The app is not NGen'd.");
                Console.WriteLine("NGen'ing the app...");

                var assemblyPath = process.MainModule.FileName;

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                // TODO: Determine the path to (the appropriate version of)
                // ngen.exe.
                // FORNOW: Just use a hardcoded path to ngen.exe for PoC.
                startInfo.FileName =
                    @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "install \"" + assemblyPath + "\"";
                // TBD: process options that you think make sense
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                try
                {
                    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                    {
                        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    // TBD: error handling that you think makes sense - e.g.
                    // logging or displaying the error, moving on regardless
                    // etcetera.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // FORNOW: for PoC debugging and sanity checking
                Console.WriteLine("The app is already NGen'd.");
            }

            /*
             * Carry on with whatever your app does.
             */
        }
    }
}
```

### first run

```
C:\bin\SelfNgenPoC>.\SelfNgenPoC.exe
IL Image: C:\bin\SelfNgenPoC.exe
The app is not NGen'd.
NGen'ing the app...
Microsoft (R) CLR Native Image Generator - Version 4.0.30319.18408
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>    Compiling assembly C:\bin\SelfNgenPoC.exe (CLR v4.0.30319) ...

C:\bin\SelfNgenPoC>
```

### subsequent run

```
C:\bin\SelfNgenPoC>.\SelfNgenPoC.exe
Native Image: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\SelfNgenPoC\a461633
0444188e116025424c70d15f1\SelfNgenPoC.ni.exe
The app is already NGen'd.

C:\SelfNgenPoC>
```

## *Will it cause any problems later?*

Whether it makes sense to NGen an assembly depends on many factors, which you can review in [an MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2007/09/15/to-ngen-or-not-to-ngen.aspx), [NGen documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [an older but relevant "MSDN Magazine" article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163808.aspx), and elsewhere.

Ultimately only you know enough about your app to determine whether it makes sense to NGen (any, some, or all of) its assemblies.

Assuming it *does* make sense in your situation, I don't expect it will cause any distinct problems based on what you have described.

Just be sure to keep standard NGen responsibilities in mind - particularly this one noted in the NGen MSDN documentation...

> Images need to be regenerated when the original assembly or one of its dependencies is serviced.

...which should be manageable with a little fancier self-NGen'ing logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using dotNEt > 4.5

```
public App(){
    ProfileOptimization.SetProfileRoot(@"C:\MyApp");
    ProfileOptimization.StartProfile("Start.Profile");
}
```

Put this on the very start of your programm. The profile is created the first time your app is starting/profile is missing. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.profileoptimization)

Comment: `ProfileOptimization` is great if an app is running on .NET 4.5 and a multi-core processor, but its impact is typically not as significant as NGen's: see a related SO answer for [MS's own confirmation of this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979173/1810429).  I can't bring myself to downvote your answer because it is fair to mention `ProfileOptimization` even if the OP asked specifically asked about NGen; but it's not an apples-to-apples choice between them.